# How i can get 2 loaders on same page. I am Using pace.js

Tags: javascript, html, css, pace.js

[image]

This is the loader I am working on.  The loader portion is working fine. But I also want to move that "balloon" div along with loader, like when the loader is on 0 the balloon will be like down, and when the loader is 100%, the balloon will move upwards like 150px up.

This is the HTML.

```
<div class="main-load">
    <div class="small-icon">
    </div>
    <div class="pace pace-inactive">
        <div class="pace-progress" style="transform: translate3d(100%, 0px, 0px);" data-progress-text="100%" data-progress="99">
            <div class="pace-progress-inner">
            </div>
        </div>
        <div class="pace-activity">
        </div>
    </div>
    <div class="ballon">
    </div>
    <div class="load-text">
        <strong>Be patient</strong>... Great Adventures Await!
    </div>
</div>
```

This is some extra script I have included all the stuff along with loader.

```
<script type="text/javascript">
    $(document).ready(function() {      
        $("<div class='main-load'></div>").appendTo( "body.pace-running" );
        $(".pace").appendTo( ".main-load" );
        $("<div class='small-icon'></div>").appendTo( ".main-load").insertBefore(".pace");
        $("<div class='ballon'></div>").appendTo( ".main-load" );
        $("<div class='load-text'><strong>Be patient</strong>... Great Adventures Await!</div>").appendTo( ".main-load" );
    });

    /*Pace js fucntion*/
    Pace.on('hide', function(){
        console.log('done');
        if($('body#top').hasClass('pace-done') == true)
            $('.main-load').hide();
        else
            $('.main-load').show();
    });
</script>
```

Comment: please reformat your code.

Comment: Unfortunately for us all Stack Overflow is not a place where you dump your code and someone does your work for you. What have you tried so far? What are the errors you got when you tried it? Those are the questions that people can help you with.